# Did Hardy prove that there are countably, or uncountably many zeros on the line Re$(s)=1/2$ of $\zeta(s)$?

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

It's known that Hardy proved that there are infinitely many zeros of $\zeta(s)$ on the line Re$(s)=\frac{1}{2}$, but did he prove it's countably infinite? Or uncountable?

Comment: the Weierstrass factorization theorem  tells us that a meromorphic function has at most countably many zeros/poles in the complex plane, while the Riemann $\Xi(s^{1/2})$ function is entire and of order $1/2$ so has an infinity of zeros

Answer (score 6):

There's a nifty property of meromorphic functions: they have isolated zeros. Construct a ball of radius $\delta$ around each zero such that no two zeros of $\zeta$ belong to the same ball. The set comprising all these neighborhoods must have countably many connected components, since each open neighborhood contains $x+iy$ with $x$ and $y$ rational; thus each component has a rational representative, and there are countably many rational complex numbers.

Comment: ... and to answer the question asked, it's pretty certain that Hardy would have realised this.

Answer (score 4):

By the identity theorem and the fact that uncountable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must have at least one limit point, any holomorphic function having uncountably many zeroes must vanish identically on its domain. $\zeta$ is holomorphic on a region excluding the origin, so it must not have uncountably many zeroes.